# What different vehicles do: drive, swim, fly

Tags: word-choice

Travelling on land in a vehicle is inarguably *driving*:

> The car drives.

But in case of travelling on water, the situation is not as unambiguous (at least in German).

What does a *ship* do (in English)? Does it *swim* or *drive*?

What does a *submarine* do?

Do all kinds of aeroplanes *fly*?

Do any other vehicles have any special mobility verbs?

Answer (score 2):

- a ship **sails**
- a submarine **dives** then **navigates/cruises** and finally **surfaces**
- a plane **takes off** then **flies** and finally **lands**
- a helicopter **flies** and **hovers**
- a bicycle **rides**
- a motorbike **rides**
- a bus **runs** or **goes**
- a train **runs**
- a car **drives**
- a person (normally) **walks** or **runs**

It's unclear whether it's correct to say that submarines **cruise** deep under water, I feel that they *cruise* above or just below the surface of the water but in any case, the verbs *cruise* and *navigate* are both appropriate. The important message to take back home is that **submarines do not *swim***.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine_navigation)

> - Submarines carry an inertial navigation system, which measures the boat’s motion and constantly updates position. Because it does not rely on radio signals or celestial sightings, it allows the boat **to navigate** while remaining hidden under the surface.

and from the website [How Stuff Works](https://science.howstuffworks.com/transport/engines-equipment/submarine4.htm)

> - The inertial guidance systems are accurate to 150 hours of operation and must be realigned by other surface-dependent navigational systems (GPS, radio, radar, satellite). With these systems onboard, a submarine can be accurately **navigated** and be within a hundred feet of its intended course.

From [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?lr=lang_en&tbs=lr%3Alang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=RimrXMqSG8qFmwXo8riwBg&q=%22submarine%20cruised%22&oq=%22submarine%20cruised%22&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.241746.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1c..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.kq102VJiV2o)

- *That night, the American submarine **cruised** on the surface, charging her “can,” as submariners call the huge storage batteries*
- *The ocean floor was abundant with sea anemones, strange ocean plants and deep rocky holes from which peeked little white eels! "We created these pyramids for the fish to live," said the pilot as the submarine **cruised** through the deep water.*
- *During World War II, an average submarine **cruised** at nine knots for only a half hour, or at five knots for six hours, or at three knots for eighteen hours.*

Comment: That's a great list, thx! What does a submarine do between diving and surfacing? Does it *swim* or *drive* or something else? Do bikes *ride* only, or do they *drive* as well? The same question about buses and trains.

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet neither motorbikes nor bicycles (bikes can mean either!) drive. To drive a vehicle it is my understanding that a steering wheel is needed. You can drive a bus, lorry, truck, van etc. As for the submarine, I think it either floats or sinks underwater.

Comment: A submarine can “sail” or “cruise” from place to place, according to [https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/does-a-submarine-cruise-underwater-or-sail-underwater](link).

Comment: @whiskeychief I saw that answer too but I've never heard of a submarine sailing. I am about to update the answer.

Comment: These are really good! I'd also mention that some vehicles can have specialized movement verbs based on their form of propulsion. It seems like the older the method is, the more broadly it applies. All ships "sail" even though many no longer have sails. Ships with engines can be said to "steam" even if they aren't steam engines--and so can trains, for that matter.